# How to type-enforce object value to match object key?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have objects that implements types like this:

```js
type TMyObject<T extends string> {
  category: T
}
```

I need to statically store them in an other object, and ensure that the key of this second object matches the value of the `category` field, like so:

```js
const myObject: TMyObject<'foo'> = { category: 'foo' }

const dico = {
  foo: myObject, // good
  bar: myObject, // bad: 'bar' key does not match myObject.category
}
```

I encounter this case, because I have interfaces that extends `IMyObject` and fixes the category field to a precise value, like so:

```js
type TMyFooObject = IMyObject<'foo'>
```

I spent two hours trying to create a type for the `dico` object that would work as described, but I just cannot figure a way to solve this ^^

Important note: The `category` field and the possibles types extending `TMyObject` are not static, we cannot use a "simple" union here...

**As ever, a huge thanks for the time spent reading, and maybe answering to this question !**

Comment: That seems to be a runtime check, not a compile time check, because you can always have an implementation of `IMyObject` with some other string value in there.

Comment: @AndreiTătar I edited the question to use generic type instead of interface to clarify the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can make use of [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to define the values of an object based on their key.

```
type Dico<Keys extends string> = {
    [K in Keys]: TMyObject<K>
}
```

If we know all of the categories beforehand then we can create a map with those categories as keys.

```
const dico: Dico<'foo' | 'bar'> = {
  foo: { category: 'foo' }, // good
  bar: { category: 'foo' }, // error: Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type '"bar"'
}
```

You could use `Partial<Dico<Category>>` if you want to limit it to a set of valid categories but not require all of them to be present.

This makes sense only if your types are setup such that you already have an easy way to access a union type of all of the categories.

We want to be able to just look at an object and see if its keys match its category strings.  We can do that, but only if we create the object through an identity function.  A generic function allows us to infer the `Keys` type from the object.

```
const makeDico = <Keys extends string>(dico: Dico<Keys>) => dico;

const dico = makeDico({
  foo: { category: 'foo' }, // good
  bar: { category: 'foo' }, // error: Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type '"bar"'
});
// dico has type: Dico<"foo" | "bar">
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Nd3AQw)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ! Huge thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As long as `IMyObject` has a `cateogory` of type `string` this is a runtime check, not a compile time check.

You can enforce the check to be a compile time check with specific types for each of your cases:

```
interface IFooObject {
  category: 'foo';
  foo: number;
  //other foo props
}

interface IBarObject {
  category: 'bar';
  bar: number;
  //other bar props
}

type IObject = IFooObject | IBarObject;

const myObject: IObject = { category: 'foo', foo: 123 }

type Disco<T> = T extends { category: infer U } ? U extends string ? { [P in U]: T } : never : never;

const disco: Disco<IObject> = {
  foo: myObject, // good
  bar: myObject, // this now fails!
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2mDyAjAKwgTGQG8AoZZBOSAc0ygE8AuZAchmw4G4rk3TOxABXALZ5o-agHpZmMAAtog7MgAOUTBoDOFAL4UKoSLEQpUAIThR8REuQG0GTNpzy2+Az1BESpKBlkeUUVKGRfTW09Q2MwZg1Le2JSAF40LFxCVOQAHzQbOxySfgoETBBdUnFmFJJ2VHr08ho6CEYWdi4eABo1YWQARgAmAGZkIwoEpOQAEWBdCoAeABUAPmQM1eQIAA9IEAATXVaXDrd2UBhVAFVJ5AB+ZHv9w5PkaqhQeifWgG0AArIUAvAC67B2BmQIggADdVLCEUFjBUqqQjosKuwFktMMsmiUwJsMpRqEJ2LVmv15MhGJgjj5bJS6kSabJkMpFsgQJgAO6CODAAA2ugAhIZeEA)

You can also use the generic type, but in that case you need to pass it all the way like:

```
type TMyObject<T extends string> = {
  category: T
}

const myObject: TMyObject<'foo'> = { category: 'foo' }

type Disco<T> = T extends { category: infer U } ? U extends string ? { [P in U]: T } : never : never;

const dico: Disco<typeof myObject> = {
  foo: myObject, // good
  bar: myObject, // bad: 'bar' key does not match myObject.category
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgsiA8gIwFYQMbADwyhAD2AgDsATAZyguACcBLEgcwD4oBeKAbwCgooMAQ2JMA9rRAAuWDwC%20PHhlEkaUALZI0mYNPib0WbAHIAZqNFG2nLgOEQxE6afNGo8nqEhQAIvQpLcK1h8IlJKblsRcSkoRhMIWigAVTcoAH5kkOJyKhoGZnSIgG0ABViSZIBdXVTpEggANwSoOsaEgG4FJRVgKDJ6JWlff1FsTwhRE3V9bSDefjNRaQ0UA2AAGigAei2oMVEyPihkQVplmaxNnePBMicT2lcAawgQPtEIKhJRXrVhDAAFtNVtoAHRCKISOQ8IA)

Comment: This solution requires to enumerate the types (as you do in `IObject`)... If there is a way to make it generic, my problem is solved ! :-)

Comment: @Miaow added a way with the generic type. I don't see how else you could enforce it without runtime checks.